# How do I get justifiedGallery plugin to work with multiple galleries?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using this wonderful jquery plugin called [justified gallery](http://miromannino.github.io/Justified-Gallery/). Below is a simplified html syntax to use this plugin, followed by javascript syntax.

**HTML**

```
<div id="my-gallery">
    <a href="path/to...............">
        <img src="path/to/............1.jpg" />
    </a>
    <a href="path/to...............">
        <img src="path/to/............2.jpg" />
    </a>
    .......
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script>jQuery("#my-gallery").justifiedGallery({
    rowHeight : 120,
    margins : 0 
});</script>
```

**ISSUE** - With the above code the plugin is working just fine BUT only for the first instance of the html syntax. Meaning, if I try `<div id="my-gallery">......</div>` twice or more on the same page, it only works on the first instance. Since there is going to be multiple galleries on a same page I **need this to loop**.

I can handle php well but yet to start learning javascript so unable to hack the javascript. If it was only php I would have generated different ids for each gallery with something like the code below.

```
$arr = array('first_gallery', 'second_gallery', 'third_gallery'); 
$i = 0;
foreach($arr as $a){
echo '<div id="my-gallery-'.$i.'">'.$a. '</div><br>';
$i++;   
}
```

The code above would have resulted to this in the view-source.

```
<div id="my-gallery-0">first_gallery</div><br>
<div id="my-gallery-1">second_gallery</div><br>
<div id="my-gallery-2">third_gallery</div><br>
```

So the question is, is my logic correct to solve this, if yes then (since my javascript is nill) how do I solve this in context of my javascript. Any response if appreciated. TIA.

Comment: As `id` must be unique (i.e. you can't have two or more `<div id="my-gallery">`) can you give each one the same `class` and use that instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a class instead. **[An ID must be unique.](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute)** Having multiple identical IDs is invalid HTML. Output as follows:

```
$arr = array('first_gallery', 'second_gallery', 'third_gallery'); 

foreach($arr as $a){
  echo '<div class="my-gallery">'.$a. '</div><br>';
}
```

And use Javascript then like this. (Note that a [document ready event](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) might be required!)

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".my-gallery").justifiedGallery({
       rowHeight : 120,
       margins : 0 
  });
</script>
```

Using `br` in HTML for this purpose is discouraged. If your elements are block elements and are not floated or absolutely positioned, you won't need `br`. If you want some space between them you can set a margin is CSS (and remove `br`):

```
.my-gallery {margin: 24px auto;}
```

---

If you want to keep the unique ID on the gallery items (I don't know why, it seems pointless and needless markup to me, but anyway) you can do it like this:

```
$arr = array('first_gallery', 'second_gallery', 'third_gallery'); 
$i = 0;
foreach($arr as $a){
  echo '<div class="my-gallery" id="my-gallery-'.$i.'">'.$a. '</div><br>';
  $i++;   
}
```

Comment: @gurung You're welcome. If this answer helped you, please accept it by checking the check mark on the left!

Answer (score 3):

You are not allowed to have multiple element with identical id's... so having two or more `<div id="my-gallery">` is invalid HTML.

Instead give each one a `class`, and use that class name as the selector in your jQuery.

```
<div id="my-gallery1" class="my-gallery-class">
   ...
</div>
<div id="my-gallery2" class="my-gallery-class">
   ...
</div>

$(function(){
  $(".my-gallery-class").each(function(){
    $(this).justifiedGallery({
      rowHeight : 120,
      margins : 0 
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have suggested you can give each gallery a common class and use that in your JavaScript

eg:

```
<div class="gallery" id="my-gallery-0">first_gallery</div><br>
<div class="gallery" id="my-gallery-1">second_gallery</div><br>
<div class="gallery" id="my-gallery-2">third_gallery</div><br>


<script>
    jQuery(".gallery").justifiedGallery({
    rowHeight : 120,
    margins : 0 
});
</script>
```